# Use Linq to create sub lists grouped by a property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of surveys which is a custom class. The surveys contain a property called `UWI`. I want to create multiple lists for each unique `UWI`.

A tricky part is, a UWI is a location. It can be written out as `00/01-08-023-23W4/0`  The last character of the string (0 in this case) tells you the event underground at which it takes place, and the first part is the surface location. I want to group all of the UWI's by the surface location not taking into account the depth.

For example:

> 00/01-08-023-23W4/0

and

> 00/01-08-023-23W4/3

are the same surface location but they have different events, so these should be grouped.

While trying to work through the problem I tried:

```
 var test =  directionalSurveys.Select(a => a.UWI.Remove(a.UWI.Length - 1, 1));
```

This just returned a single list of UWI's.

If the main list had 5 objects in its collection:

> 00/01-08-023-23W4/0
>
> 00/01-08-023-23W4/1
>
> 00/01-08-023-23W4/2
>
> 00/01-06-028-19W4/0
>
> 00/01-04-018-15W4/0

The end result would be 3 new lists. The first 3 as a list, the fourth one as a list, and the fifth one as a list.

Comment: Can there ever be 10  or more underground events?

Comment: I have never seen it, but it is a possibility

Comment: Then you should consider a different mechanism to extract out the end - it'll fail if that happens.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` to group the items:

```
var query = directionalSurveys.GroupBy(a => a.UWI.Remove(a.UWI.Length - 1, 1));
```